# How to solve this exact division problem?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $p\in \mathbb{N}^{+}$ and $a_i\in\{0,2\}$ for $i=1,2,\cdots, p$.
If $3^{p}-1\mid(3^{p-1}a_{1}+3^{p-2}a_2+3^{p-3}a_3+\cdots+3a_{p-1}+a_p)^2$, then how can we prove
$$\dfrac{(3^{p-1}a_{1}+3^{p-2}a_2+3^{p-3}a_3+\cdots+3a_{p-1}+a_p)^2}{3^{p}-1}\in\{0,3^{p}-1\}\cup\{\mbox{odd numbers}\}.$$
First, when $p=1,2,3$ this is correct. Then I do not know how to prove this by induction? If you have any idea of this problem, I will appreciate a lot.

Comment: Can you show your work for $p=3$? EG Did you approach it by trying all cases? Were you able to get all odd numbers (up to some limit) or just a subset of them?

Comment: when $p=3$, then $3^{p}-1\mid(3^{p-1}a_{1}+3^{p-2}a_2+3^{p-3}a_3+\cdots+3a_{p-1}+a_p)^2$ becomes $26\mid(9a_1+3a_2+a_3)^2,$ note that $a_i\in\{0,2\}$. Therefore, there are only $8$ cases. Clearly, only two cases have the division property, i.e. $a_i=0$ or $a_i=2$ for any $i=1,2,3$. So, we are done. I am not sure whether we can prove it by induction. The odd number is just a subset of them.

Comment: Roughly speaking, if we have the division property, then the quotient must be an odd number except $3^p-1.$